# Show/Hide Divs after javascript action

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a jsfiddle that allows the user to click on a square and the square expands. What I want to do is allow a separate div to appear once a div is clicked. For example, if the first div is clicked, I want the transition to happen and then text to appear over the green.

Here is the javascript I am using:

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        setTimeout(function (div) {
            return function () { div.css('z-index', '') ; } ;
        } ($(this)), 1000) ;
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('z-index', 400) ;
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked') ;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eD56Y/11/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UawH4/

You can add a div with append() and remove it when you collapse the box with remove().

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        setTimeout(function (div) {
            return function () { div.css('z-index', '') ; } ;
        } ($(this)), 1000) ;
        $('#addedDiv').remove();
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('z-index', 400) ;
        $(this).append('<div id="addedDiv">Here is some text</div>');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked') ;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works, but the transition is lost. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) { 
if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
    setTimeout(function (div) {
        return function () { div.css('z-index', '') ; } ;
    } ($(this)), 1000) ;
   $( ".first_box" ).empty();        
}
else {
    $(this).css('z-index', 400) ;
}
$(this).toggleClass('clicked') ;
$('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('.first_box');
```

});

The content `<p>text></p>` will appear in the div .first_box if clicked (and so if it gets bigger)

Comment: The transition is lost, is there a way to fix this? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: i made an error in the code.. there are }); to add in the code at the end (in the post they got out of the code tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "show" class to content div and it will transition in the content with opacity 0 to 1:

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        setTimeout(function (div) {
            return function () { div.css('z-index', '') ; } ;
        } ($(this)), 1000) ;
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('z-index', 400) ;
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked') ;
    //make sure to show the content in the clicked div.
    $(this).find('.content').toggleClass('show');

});
```

And the CSS changes:

```
.content {
    opacity: 0;
}

.content.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Edit: To keep colors of expanded content:** Just add extra css classes to keep the content background color once clicked. See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eD56Y/14/):

```
.first_box.clicked {
    background-color: green;
}

.second_box.clicked {
    background-color: blue;
}

.third_box.clicked {
    background-color: red;
}

.fourth_box.clicked {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks! Is there a way to keep the hover color on once its expanded, even if you take your mouse off?

Comment: Add css class to keep color once expanded... Please accept answer if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the text is outside the rest of the divs.

You can try this.

[fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/QBdDE/)

HTML

```
<section class="overlay-text"><h3>Some Text</h3></section>
<div class="first_box"></div>
<div class="second_box"></div>
<div class="third_box"></div>
<div class="fourth_box"></div>
```

JS

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        setTimeout(function (div) {
            return function () { div.css('z-index', '') ; } ;            
        } ($(this)), 1000) ;
       $('.overlay-text').hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('z-index', 400) ;
        setTimeout(function(){$('.overlay-text').show();},1000);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked') ;

});
```

Added CSS

```
.overlay-text {
    position:absolute;  
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    width: 289px !important ;
    height: 289px !important ;
    margin-top: 0 !important ;
    margin-left: 0 !important ;
    z-index:500;
    pointer-events:none;
}

h3{color:white;}
```

Comment: This works really well. One more question, is there a way to keep the hover color on even if the mouse rolls off?

Comment: I added a background-color to overlay. Thanks!